# Get the records periodicaly using sql query

Tags: sql, linq

I have below situation.I have one table named `UserCheckIn`.
This contain the below column
`Id, UserId, CheckInTime, CheckOutTime, CheckInStatus`.
I want number of user `checkedin` in hourly, daily, weekly. Lets consider as hourly, like i will take hours 8 am -9 am, 9 am to 10 am etc. I want one `sql/linq` statement give result me in array or list format like 11,23,12.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: select count (*) from table name where CheckInTime in (myvalue1, myvalue2)

Comment: If  i need checkin user of  last 24 hours with hourly basis, how can i get this? According to Aditya I need to fire query in 24 time, Is their is any way in sql or linq, I can get result in single query..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) for this.

Create events as per your requirement. Hourly/Daily/Monthly etc.
Here is the [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) for your perusal.  This has detailed information and sample codes as well. Please note your DB user needs to have required privileges for Events creation/usage.